# Vue-test-utils wrapper undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I have the following test suite in Jest for a component. I have successfully written unit tests for several other components that follow a similar structure:

```
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import storeMock from '@mocks/store'
import RequestProposalsContainer from '@/components/RequestProposals/RequestProposalsContainer'

describe('ProviderComparison component', () => {
  let localVue, store, wrapper, storeSetup

  beforeEach(() => {
     localVue = createLocalVue()
     localVue.use(Vuex)

     storeSetup = storeMock()
     store = new Vuex.Store(storeSetup)
     /* wrapper is undefined and I'm not sure why */
     wrapper = mount(RequestProposalsContainer, {
       localVue,
       store
     })
  })

  it('renders correct structure', () => {
     /* undefined */
     console.log('wrapper: ', wrapper)
  })
})
```

By inspection, the component being mounted, the store, and localVue instance are well-defined.

Comment: Any clues from the console? Do you have a link to a GitHub repo that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I took a look at more of the console errors and it turned out I needed to add necessary fields in the mock store, as well as add a stub for the router. Question has been resolved.

Comment: @AdamFreymiller could you post your solution here and accept it?

Comment: @AdamFreymiller please share the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in a similar situation where the `wrapper` would come back undefined.

While testing, you have to give the component everything it needs to render.

It was (as @Adam Freymiller has already alluded to) that all the required values (props, store values, etc) were not set in the test, so the component would error out, much like how it would in a real life scenario.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what the component needs? or if a nested component is failing?

Comment: Check all the props/imports that are used within the component. Child components can be mocked I believe.